# Selecting max value when joining RichPipes

Tags: scala, hadoop, scalding

I have a list of `RichPipes` with the following fields:

- name: `String`
- joinTime: `Long`
- value: `Int`

I want to join them sequentially using reduce. When joining the `RichPipes` I only want to retain one field, `value`, and I want it to contain the max value from the joint `RichPipes`. How can I do it?

Comment: What if I used ++ to concatenate the pipes and then did groupBy(('name, 'joinTime)) { group => group.max('value -> 'maxValue)}?

Comment: That could work, and it will translate into 1 reduce phase.  The alternative which would be chain of joins would result in as many reduce phases as you have RichPipes.  So you seem to have answered your own question :)